# Deleting posts of other Facebook applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to delete thousands of old posts on a Facebook page made by another (discontinued) application.

From what I gather reading the documentation an application can remove only the posts made by itself. This is a reasonable default, but it prevents the development of any kind of administrative or cleanup applications, so I wonder if this is really the case.

Is there a way to mass delete posts made by an application? (If not through the API, perhaps through the UI?)

Comment: You can write an Automated script using selenium or any other. To click on "delete" button and say "YES" to confirm, for all posts that match the condition you give.

Comment: @bozzmob I have thought of it, but while deleting by hand I observed that the UI is extremely unreliable. You go through the posts listed for a certain time period, delete them all, only to discover more after listing them again later. Quite infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to go through the page feed with `/page-id/feed` and delete them one by one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post#deleting

You are right though, you can only delete posts made by that App - most likely for safety reasons. A malicious App could just delete all Page entries.

Comment: “An app can delete a post if it published it”